# Dynamically created multipage with checkbox, how can I trigger a CheckBox1_Change() event?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a template multipage page.
[image]

This template is then copied with `Me.MP.Pages.Item(0).Controls.Copy` and pasted `Me.MP.Pages(p).Paste` the `UserForm_Initialize` and the labels and listbox is filled with data from the sheet.
When the form is loaded there could be anywhere from 0 to 100 pages.

How can I detect the change in the checkbox?
So far I have only managed to create this code:

```
Private Sub MP_Change()

    Debug.Print Me.MP.Pages(Me.MP.Value).Controls(3).Value
    
End Sub
```

This code prints when I change page on the mulipage, but there is no guarantee you change pages. There could be just 1 page.

What I need is to record the checkbox true/false value on a sheet. The above code could do that if you switch pages back and forth.
I could also create a `UserForm_Terminate()` and iterate all the pages and record it then.
That would work, but I'm looking for the cleaner event method.
Is that even possible?

Comment: Firstly, why do you need copying a (simple) check box instead of creating it on the flay? Secondly, how many such check boxes may be involved? From 1 to 5 or more? Then, if many, based on what the code to identify each such check box being changed? I suppose that each such changed check box control should determine a (different) action for each. Am I wrong? I know how to create events for such controls, but to do something useful (not only demonstrating how it is possible) I need some context... There are two ways: preliminarily declaring the objects or creating a class and allocating events.

Comment: `why do you need copying a (simple) check box instead of creating it on the flay?` Because there could be 0 to 100 pages as I mentioned above. The checkbox is a minor thing on the Multipage, the listbox can contain from 1 to 27 rows of data. like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLONA.png or this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdsiG.png . I'm not keen on creating these pages manually. YMMV. But on each page there is one checkbox as in the images. I don't understand why you assume there are more than what the image shows.

Comment: But no, I don't need to indentify which box is pressed since there is just one per page. And it's not the checkbox I copy. It's the complete multipage page

Comment: Ups... I superficially understood that you copy only the check box you need to trigger its event. Now, do you want copying so many pages on the fly, **not keeping them after terminating the form**?

Comment: Yes, I don't need to keep them. They change all the time. One day a page is there, the next day it's not. Its dynamic. The only time I would benefit from keeping the pages would be if I open the form again the same day, could happen but unlikely.

Comment: OK. Are there on the for other check boxes except the one to be copied? Of course, the copied ones, too...

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. But the template multipage has one checkbox, two labels and one listbox. All these items are copied to each new page added. All pages look exactly the same, only the text in the listbox and one of the labels are different

Comment: I meant, on a form (besides MultiPage control) a lot of other controls my exist. The question wants to refer to the fact that no other check boxes exists on that forms except the one on the first page and the copied onces. I intend to design a class able to allocate a specific event and I need to know if the respective form does not already have another check box having its specific event (to be kept as it is...)

Comment: Please, test the solution I posted. I design the event allocations to be done  only for the check boxes from the `MultiPage` control pages. So, even if other check box controls exists on the form (besides the ones on the multi page control pages) they will keep their existing event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use the next way to allocate click event to all copied check boxes:

1. Insert a class module and name it **CheckBoxCls**, then copy the next simple code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents chkBEvent As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chkBEvent_Click()
    MsgBox "Check box from page " & chkBEvent.Parent.name & " was clicked." & vbCrLf & _
           "Its value is: " & chkBEvent.Value
End Sub
```

It contains the Click event, able to identify on which MultiPage page the clicked check box exists and what value it has. Please, adapt it to do what **you really need it to do**.

2. Copy the next declaration on top of the User Form code module (in the declarations area):

```
 Private chkB() As New CheckBoxCls
```

3. I tested this solution using the next (simple) example code to also allocate the class event to all copied check boxes (after controls copying). You should adapt your existing code in this way, or even keep it as it is (instead of yours) if yours does not also do something else:

```
Dim p As Long, ctrl As MSForms.Control, k As Long

   Me.MultiPage1.Pages.item(0).Controls.Copy
   
   ReDim chkB(Me.Controls.count) 'an initial maximum number of controls
   For p = 1 To Me.MultiPage1.Pages.count - 1 'start copying from the second page
    Me.MultiPage1.Pages(p).Paste
    For Each ctrl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(p).Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            Set chkB(k).chkBEvent = ctrl: k = k + 1: Exit for 'allocate event
        End If
     Next ctrl
   Next p
   
   ReDim Preserve chkB(k - 1) 'keep only loaded check boxes
```

Now, play with ticking/un-ticking each involved check box and see how it works.

Note: Your first check box must have its own event already created. If not, it is not complicated to also add it automatically.

If something not clear, plese do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: I have not got it working yet. I can see the messages come when the form is Initialize because below "your" code there is some code that sets their base value depending on what is on the sheet. I don't have time to debug it more now. I will have a look at it tomorrow again

Comment: @Andreas Not seeing your code, I imagined  something able to do all the stuff in the same iteration. If you change/initialize each check box after its pasting, it looks better to allocate the event at the end of the code in **a second iteration**. For 100 pages it should take less than a second... Disabling events in a form does not work as it should, unfortunately...

Comment: @Andreas If still adapting the code looks problematic, I can connect to your computer and see what is it about. Of course, if not something confidential and you have AnyDesk on your computer (even not installed)...

Comment: This is the current state of the code. I realize that posting images is not the best, but it's certainly better than posting code in comments :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/awRuf.png You can see the class is there, the declaration is at the top of userform code. I first tried to make the two loops in to one by just renaming your ctrl to ctl as in my loop and jamming it in there. Didn't work. I have enableevents false at the top and true at the bottom of this sub. Just below the screen there is just end if and next col. As you can see in the debug window the code runs initialize but not ever

Comment: again. Let me have a few minutes to look at it and I will see what I can do. The reason the code outputs in debug window is because I changed it to debug.print and the second last line in the image sets the value of the checkbox to true on three of the printers. That makes the code run. Then after the userform loads I can't get it to print anything again.

Comment: Found the issue, needed to move the redim to above the loop. Should have seen that earlier. Thank you!